# Android Studio can't download packages

Tags: download, android-studio, proxy, package

I can't start Android Studio after installing it, this is the error:

> sys-img-x68-addon-google_apis-google-21, extra-android-m2repository
>   and 3 more SDK components were not installed

And this is the log:

```
Android SDK was installed to C:\Users\Vincent\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
Refresh Sources:
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources

Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Download finished with wrong size. Expected 159505060 bytes, got 1527 bytes.
  Download finished with wrong size. Expected 1848028 bytes, got 1537 bytes.
  Download finished with wrong size. Expected 271448751 bytes, got 1559 bytes.
  Download finished with wrong size. Expected 41693483 bytes, got 1533 bytes.
  Download finished with wrong size. Expected 39017864 bytes, got 1531 bytes.
  Done. Nothing was installed.
sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21, extra-android-m2repository and 3 more SDK components were not installed
```

Note: I am on a proxy server but I have setup my proxy settings
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: getting same error as yours. have you solved it?

Comment: @Android_Rocks there isn't really a fix but there is a workaround, once I'm on my PC i'l contact you, you have to use a VPN, if you know anyone who has one just ask him if you can connect to it, else you could connect to mine for a moment so that the studio can install. Sorry for bad English, I'm dutch